# update the input XML file with namespace in JAVA using DOM parser

Tags: java, xml, dom

How to update the XML node from `<ns0:Request>` to `<ns1:Request xmlns:ns1="with some URL">`
in Java using DOM parser.
I do not want to use the `replaceAll()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following using the `Node.replaceChild(Node, Node)` method:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#replaceChild%28org.w3c.dom.Node,%20org.w3c.dom.Node%29

```java
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        // Create original document
        Document document = db.newDocument();
        Element root = document.createElementNS("urn:FOO", "ns0:Root");
        document.appendChild(root);
        Element request = document.createElementNS("urn:FOO", "ns0:Request");
        root.appendChild(request);

        // Create new Request element.
        Element newRequest = document.createElementNS("urn:BAR", "ns1:Request");

        // Replace Request element
        root.replaceChild(newRequest, request);

        // Output the new document
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        t.transform(source, result);
    }

}
```